# How to store/query ledger data in couchdb or any other nosql DB in hyperledger

Tags: couchdb, hyperledger, peer, nosql

Can we store the distributed ledger data in some nosql db whenever new transaction happens.If so what are steps involved in this job.

Once we stored the data into nosql then how can we able to query the data from peers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [Ledger Interface](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/ledger/ledger_interface.go) with nosql backend of your choice. The interaction with db implemented on chaincode level base on [ChaincodeStubInterface](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/core/chaincode/shim/interfaces.go) API.

Just to note, that Hyperledger Fabric has solution based on couchdb, so instead of plugging your own, you might consider to use it.